# CSS appendTo("");

Tags: jquery, appendto

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("[href]").appendTo(" Click here ...");});
```

HTML Code

```
<a href="#"> b </a>
```

I want to to show it on browser as
b Click here ...
But i didn't work properly here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is vague. Please share your example in jsfiddle for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried  *append* instead of *appendTo* ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("[href]").append(" Click here ...");});
```

from my understanding it works like:

```
element.append('stuff to append to the element');
```

vs

```
element.appendTo(otherElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use direct tag selector and also `append` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("a").append(" Click here ...");

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[href]").append(" Click here ...");
});​
```

Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function instead of .appendTo() function.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jk84K/)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$("[href]").appendTo(" Click here ...");
```

To:

```
$("[href]").html(" Click here ...");
```

With `appendTo`, you are supposed to add a new DOM element not text node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `append()` rather than `appendTo()`.

`append()` simply takes the text or jQuery element that you supply as an argument and appends it as the last child of the element that you have selected - I think this is the behavious you are looking for. The documentation for `append()` is at http://api.jquery.com/append/ if you want to look into it more.

Answer (score 0):

Use ID insted of tag.If you have multiple anchor tag its work for all.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#YourID").append(" Click here ...");
    });


 <a href="#" id="YourID"> b </a>
```